# Why isn't the configuration from my application-test.properties being used?

Tags: spring, jpa, junit, h2

I am trying to run tests in my Spring application which need to use an embedded h2 database (instead of the sql database I use for the actual application). The problem I was facing was that it is executing all queries on the h2 database in upper case and it was failing because of that.

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Table "MOOD" not found; SQL statement:
insert into mood
```

Now  I figured out in application properties you can just put DATABASE_TO_LOWER=TRUE in the connection string, but this is not working for me. I can clearly see in the output that is not using the url I am defining in application-test.properties:

```
Starting embedded database: url='jdbc:h2:mem:85afe142-af28-4c3a-8226-0a77abdb004d;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=false', username='sa'
```

So the relevant files:

my application-test.properties:

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:db;DB_CLOSE_DELAY-2;DATABASE_TO_LOWER=TRUE
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=sa
```

my test class:

```
package com.example.demo.persistence.interfaces;

import com.example.demo.persistence.dto.Mood;
import com.example.demo.persistence.dto.MoodType;
import com.example.demo.persistence.dto.Patient;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.TestEntityManager;
import org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles;
import org.springframework.test.context.TestPropertySource;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Collection;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;

@DataJpaTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@TestPropertySource(locations="classpath:application-test.properties")
@EnableConfigurationProperties
class MoodRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    private TestEntityManager entityManager;

    @Autowired
    private MoodRepository repository;

    @Autowired
    private PatientRepository patientRepository;

    @Test
    void getMoodsByPatient() {
        final Patient patient = new Patient("Kees", "spek", "straat", Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
        final Patient patient2 = new Patient("Kees2", "spek2", "straat2", Calendar.getInstance().getTime());

        final Mood mood1 = new Mood(patient, MoodType.GOOD,"","","","","","","",Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
        final Mood mood2 = new Mood(patient, MoodType.GOOD,"","","","","","","",Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
        final Mood mood3 = new Mood(patient2, MoodType.GOOD,"","","","","","","",Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
        entityManager.persist(patient);
        entityManager.persist(patient2);
        entityManager.persist(mood1);
        entityManager.persist(mood2);
        entityManager.persist(mood3);

        final int expectedMoodsFound = 2;
        final int actualMoodsFound = ((Collection<?>)repository.getMoodsByPatient(patient)).size();

        assertEquals(expectedMoodsFound,actualMoodsFound);
    }

    @Test
    void getMoodByMoodId() {
    }

    @Test
    void deleteAllByDateBefore() {
    }
}
```

So my problem is, I can't seem to properly load in the application-test.properties I guess? What am I doing wrong? I read so many different things on stackoverflow and other websites and none of them worked and I feel like it's a fairly simple issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `@DataJpaTest` annotation uses the meta annotation `@AutoConfigureTestDatabase` which has the default configuration to replace any manually configured or auto-configured datasource:

```
public @interface AutoConfigureTestDatabase {

    /**
     * Determines what type of existing DataSource bean can be replaced.
     * @return the type of existing DataSource to replace
     */
    @PropertyMapping(skip = SkipPropertyMapping.ON_DEFAULT_VALUE)
    Replace replace() default Replace.ANY;


    /**
     * What the test database can replace.
     */
    enum Replace {

        /**
         * Replace the DataSource bean whether it was auto-configured or manually defined.
         */
        ANY,

        /**
         * Only replace the DataSource if it was auto-configured.
         */
        AUTO_CONFIGURED,

        /**
         * Don't replace the application default DataSource.
         */
        NONE

    }

}
```

If you want to define the database configuration on your own, you can opt-out using:

```
// ... existing annotations
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
class MoodRepositoryTest {

  // ...

}
```